# ¿Por qué el plural de régimen es "regímenes" y no "régimenes"? Y lo mismo con espécimen y carácter

Tags: plurales, acentuación

Dada la palabra régimen, el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas [indica que](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=regimen):

> **régimen**... En el plural el acento cambia de lugar: *regímenes*, no **régimenes*.

Mirando en el mismo diccionario la [entrada sobre plural](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=plural&submit.x=15&submit.y=16), veo que:

> **2. Otras cuestiones relativas al plural.**
>
> **2.1. *Cambio de la vocal tónica.*** La vocal tónica es la misma en el singular y en el plural, salvo en las palabras *espécimen, régimen* y *carácter*, en las que el acento cambia de lugar en el plural: *especímenes, regímenes* y *caracteres* [karaktéres].

Por tanto, me pregunto: ¿por qué en estas tres palabras *espécimen*, *régimen* y *carácter* la vocal tónica cambia en el plural?

Comment: Me atrevería a decir que es porque originariamente las palabras tenían la sílaba tónica en otro sitio (re**gi**men, carac**ter**), y en algún momento se desplazó en el singular pero se mantuvo en el plural.

Comment: No me atrevo a ponerlo como respuesta por que no puedo confirmarlo, pero no solo se trata de los plurales, es que no existen sustantivos sobresdrújulos y, como apunta Carlos, lo más probable es que sea tan simple como que no suenan bien, representan una dificultad añadida e innecesaria a la hora de hablar. Buscando en Google he llegado hasta aquí: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/plurales-irregulares.813878/ . Aunque no sé hasta qué punto acertada, no es de una referencia tan fiable como lo sería la RAE, es una discusión interesante y en mi opinión con argumentos acertados.

Comment: @Nox me ha fascinado ver cuáles son los plurales de _hipérbaton_ y _oxímoron_. Y fascina más aún la [explicación del DRAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=ox%C3%ADmoron) en este último: "Debe permanecer invariable en plural, ya que **no existen en español sustantivos sobresdrújulos**. También se documenta, y es válido, el plural _oxímoros_."

Comment: ojo con la palabra carácter, hay dos acepciones básicas: la de "forma de ser" y la de "gráfico que se imprime". En el primer caso, suele aparecer en singular y es común puralizarla *mal*, diciendo "carácteres". En el segundo, es común encontrarla en plural (caracteres) y por tanto *singularizarla* mal, como "caracter" (sin tilde, es decir, aguda). Especialmente en el mundo de la informática, es habitual escuchar esta última singularización, y desde luego si alguien me habla de "los caracteres" con la acentuación correcta, en mi cabeza no aparecería nunca la primera acepción que he comentado.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo la grafía que usas corresponde a vocales _cortas_ (la volcal larga se señala con una barra: *ī*). Efectivamente, en latín se trata de palabras esdrújulas: spĕcĭmen, [rĕgĭmen](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dregimen). Al ser *imparisílabos*, el acento cambia en plural: rĕgĭminis. El caso de carácter parece ser distinto.

Comment: @Rafael lo llevo pensando unos días y, efectivamente, creo que metí la pata en el comentario. Procedo a borrarlo para no crear más confusión.

Comment: @ukemi the strike in _régimenes_ you added a while ago was useful, may be worth readding (not editing myself in case you are doing so right now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Prosodic stress changes - *espécimen, régimen*

The tonic vowel shifts in these words since Spanish prosody generally<sup>1</sup> prohibits words with preantepenult stress (*sobresdrújulos*).

Thus, in the very rare case where you have a singular noun with antepenultimate stress which adds a syllable in plural (*-es*), the stress moves to accommodate:

- **ré**-gi-men →     re-**gí**-me-nes
- es-**pé**-ci-men →  es-pe-**cí**-me-nes

### Irregular latinism - *carácter*

Though the hypothetical **carácteres* would have its stress on the (theoretically) fine antepenultimate syllable, it seems that the change in tonic vowel is just an inherited quirk of how the Latin word was pronounced, not changing in its evolution to Spanish:

- cha**rac**ter → ca**rác**ter
- charac**tē**rēs → carac**te**res

> ... se exceptúa *carácter*, adaptado a la acentuación latina, cuyo plural *caracteres*<sup>10</sup> está de acuerdo con la acentuación griega y la latina...
>
> - [*Esbozo de una Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Esbozo_de_una_nueva_gram%C3%A1tica_de_la_len.html?id=FMZiAAAAMAAJ), 2.3.2b - Apelativos terminados en consonante (1973)

This retention of the Latin stress can also be seen in the Portuguese cognate:

- ca**rá**ter
- cara**te**res

### Novel words - *olécranon, múltiplex*

La Fundéu advises that *olécranon* (the upper part of the ulna) is invariant in plural:

> Como palabra esdrújula terminada en ene, *olécranon* se mantiene invariable en plural: *los olécranon* (Tiene más información en http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=plural, g.)
>
> - [Plural de olécranon](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/plural-de-olecranon-13914/)

However the word is pluralized various ways in the few examples I was able to locate of its use in print (*olecranones,*<sup>2 3 4</sup> *olecránones*<sup>5</sup>)

The word *múltiplex* / *multiplexes* is similarly ambiguous.

#### 4. Addendum: other consonant-terminal *esdrújulas*

<sup>**Note:** These are the only words in Spanish that I'm aware of that act like this; all other consonant-terminal nouns with an antepenultimate stress are either invariant in their plural form:</sup>

<sup>• *ángelus, ómnibus, páncreas, isósceles, miércoles*</sup>
 <sup>• *análisis, éxtasis, énfasis, génesis, mímesis, némesis, ósmosis, paréntesis, perífrasis, prótesis, sinéresis, síntesis* etc</sup>
 <sup>• *cáterin, trávelin*</sup>
 <sup>• *dóberman, épsilon, ómicron, oxímoron*<sup>1</sup>*, polisíndeton*</sup>
 <sup>• *júpiter*</sup>

<sup>just add an -s:</sup>

<sup>• *currículum(s), déficit(s), hábitat(s), hándicap(s)*</sup>

<sup>or remove a terminal -n before adding an -s:</sup>

<sup>• *hipérbaton / hipérbatos*</sup>
 <sup>• *oxímoron / oxímoros*<sup>1</sup></sup>

<sup><sup>1. Both plural forms accepted</sup></sup>

---

**Notes:**

<sup>1. There are some exceptions however, but as far as I am aware these are exclusively:</sup>
 <sup>a. verbs with multiple enclitics, retaining the bare verb's original stress:</sup>
  <sup>• **cóme**telo / **habiéndo**senos / **lléve**semela</sup>
 <sup>b. adverbs ending in *-mente* formed from accented adjectives:</sup>
  <sup>• **épica**mente / **difícil**mente / **común**mente</sup>

<sup>2. [*Revista Universidad Nacional Mayor de San Marcos. Facultad de Ciencias Económicas y Comerciales*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NxEiAQAAMAAJ&q=%22olecranones%22)</sup>
<sup>3. [*Manual de rehabilitación de la columna vertebral*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YP6HfF4KFxIC&pg=PT151&dq=%22olecranones%22)</sup>
<sup>4. [*Determinacion de las principales patologias cardiacas, en caninos de la zona metropolitana de guadalajara, mediante el uso de la electrocardiografia*](http://repositorio.cucba.udg.mx:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/3156/Gonzalez_Munoz_Jaime_Alberto.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)</sup>
<sup>5. [*Hiperostosis esquelética difusa idiopática: ¿existe un patrón de predominio periférico?*](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Figura-1-Estudio-radiologico-del-caso-1-A-y-B-Proyecciones-laterales-de-la-columna_fig1_327783331)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Como iba diciendo en los comentarios, como ya anotó Carlos Alejo y aún sin tener una referencia clara de la RAE, la causa que veo más probable es tan simple como que una palabra sobresdrújula no es precisamente cómoda a la hora de hablar, y de hecho, no existen sustantivos sobresdrújulos en español, y para esto sí tenemos [una referencia directa de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=xwnL0rH8RD6olZ8prm#12d):

> **(1.2) d)** Las palabras sobresdrújulas son aquellas en las que es tónica alguna de las sílabas anteriores a la antepenúltima: *CÓmetelo, haBIÉNdosenos, LLÉvesemela.*
>   En español solo son sobresdrújulas las palabras compuestas de una forma verbal y dos o tres pronombres enclíticos.

Es decir, que solo se aceptan palabras sobresdrújulas en las construcciones en las que se unen al verbo dos o tres pronombres ([pronombres enclíticos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF)), no hay más palabras sobresdrújulas.

Con esto queda claro por qué se desplaza el acento al añadir la última silaba para formar el plural, ya que si dejáramos el acento en su posición original, dichas palabras acabarían siendo sobresdrújulas, que no están permitidas.
Aunque el texto no explica la razón de todo esto, creo que al intentar decir en voz alta *régimenes* en medio de una frase, queda bastante claro que ralentiza al hablar y es incómodo.

Como ya dije en los comentarios, buscando en Google llegué a [esta discusión de los foros de la página WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/plurales-irregulares.813878/), en la que entre otros comentarios argumentan que este cambio en la silaba tónica ya se daba en el latín con otras palabras, y precisamente con las palabras que se dan como ejemplo en la pregunta original:

- Espécimen (español) - Specimen (latín)
- Régimen - Regimen
- Carácter - Character

Todas ellas sufren el mismo desplazamiento en la tónica cuando se forma el plural tanto en español como en latín, lenguaje que, que yo sepa, no tenía tildes como las conocemos en el español, pero obviamente sí tenía acentos a la hora de entonar que es donde se notaría dicho cambio.
Incluso *carácter*, aún cuando su plural no formaría una sobresdrújula, sufre ese cambio, para lo cual no tengo respuesta aparte de que el español lo heredaría del latín y los romanos a saber porque hicieron ese cambio(en hilo nombrado y enlazado se aducen algunas posibles razones, pero bueno, eso ya cada uno que lo lea y se forme su propia opinión al respecto).

Por tanto, el cambio de tónica se produciría primero para no formar palabras sobresdrújulas, y segundo por herencia directa del latín.
Desde luego no puedo asegurar a ciencia cierta la razón de esta negativa a las palabras sobresdrújulas, pero sinceramente, bastaría con la herencia del latín, y realmente las palabras sobresdrújulas son incomodas de pronunciar(aunque esto es relativo por supuesto, seguramente habrán varios idiomas con ejemplos de palabras largas con acentos en las primeras silabas, pero para un español, es muy raro). No creo que haya mucho más.