# Regla para trasladar el acento en el plural de palabras llanas acabadas en "-r"

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, plurales

Leyendo el DPD veo que la RAE recomienda trasladar el acento en el plural de *[carácter](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=car%C3%A1cter)*: *caracteres*, y no <strike>*carácteres*</strike>. Sin embargo, para *[estándar](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=est%C3%A1ndar)* sí que recomienda el plural *estándares*, pero no <strike>*estandares*</strike>.

No veo en la *Ortografía 2010* nada al respecto. ¿Existe alguna norma que diga de forma general cuándo trasladar el acento en estas palabras y cuándo no? ¿O depende esto de la etimología de cada palabra concreta? ¿O es *carácter* la única excepción?

Comment: tal vez me equivoco pero creo que carácter y caracter deberian de ser dos palabras distintas, y por lo tanto carácteres y caracteres también : 

me veo muy fácil pronunciando carácter y carácteres para hablar de personalidad y caracter y caracteres para simbolos. principalmente por que la entonación enfática que tiene la palabra carácter es lo que le da carácter, algo que no creo que un simple caracter meresca.

Answer (score 3):

*Carácter* es la única excepción:

> **g) Sustantivos y adjetivos terminados en -l, -r, -n, -d, -z, -j.** Si no van precedidas de otra consonante ([→ j](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i#1j)), forman el plural con -es: ... *color*, pl. *colores*; ... *máster*, pl. *másteres*;
>
> ...
>
> **2.1. Cambio de la vocal tónica.** La vocal tónica es la misma en el singular y en el plural, salvo en las palabras *espécimen*, *régimen* y *carácter*, en las que el acento cambia de lugar en el plural: *especímenes*, *regímenes* y *caracteres* [karaktéres].
>
> - http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i

Más información:

[¿Por qué el plural de régimen es "regímenes" y no "régimenes"? Y lo mismo con espécimen y carácter](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18445/18348)